# digiKam Uninstall from 18.04

Tags: uninstall, digikam

I installed digiKam on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Now since I don't use it I'd like it removed. I used the Ubuntu Software pkg and Removed it. But, it still shows on my Brave desktop and if I click on it, it will start up even though the pkg manager says it's not installed. I'm a new Linux user and lack the skills to track it down. When I right-click the Brave Icon one of the options is "Remove AppImage from the system" but I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Can I ask how you installed it in the first place? When you say "I used the Ubuntu Software pkg and Removed it" do you mean you installed it using the Ubuntu Software GUI application, or that you removed it with the GUI application, or both?